# Display only the decimal places in a String

Tags: java, android, string, double

I want to Converted a Double to a string.
And display only the decimal places.

On this way:

```
Double: 123.465
String: 46

Double: 1123.465
String: 46

Double: 123.46555987
String: 46
```

Now is my question how can i do that and what is the best way?

Comment: *"what is the best way?"*  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, post the code here.. If not, come back after trying.

Comment: convert double into string and split the string after decimal point

Answer (score 0):

`Double` could be converted to String using [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). Check the API docs. If you have `double` that could be unboxed to `Double` value automatically since Java 1.6 and later. To get decimals you could use second param of [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to limit the output.

```
 s.substring(s.indexOf("."), s.indexOf(".")+2)
```

or use rounding to two decimals

```
Double.valueOf(Math.round((d/(long)d)*100)/100).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the nicest method, but it works.  Just change the 123.456 to whatever value you wish, maybe put it in a method.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double fractionalPart = 123.456 % 1;
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(
                Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(fractionalPart))).substring(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to code this person's code for them when they become your co-worker?

Comment: No, I was just trying to give him a hand, I only really wrote two lines.  I wouldn't have bothered if it was a large quantity of code.

Comment: This will not provide the exact out put what OP is required.

Comment: Other than providing the word "String :" it does provide the decimal placing and formatting as OP has requested.

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

```
Double d = 123.4567;
String stringRep = Double.toString(d).split(".")[1];
//Print or use stringRep
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Double: 123.465
String: 46

Double d = new Double(123.465);
String str = String.valueOf(d);
Sytem.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("."),str.lastIndexOf(".")+2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
public static int twoDecimal(double original)
{
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(original % 1);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);

    return (int) (rounded.doubleValue() * 100);
}
```